# Access the -webkit- vendor prefix in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, css, webkit, vendor-prefix

If I were writing a JavaScript line to set a style attribute of an element it could look like this (this example: "width"):

```
document.getElementById('myDiv').style.width="50px";
```

and if there is a dash in the CSS element it would look like this (this example: "margin-top"):

```
document.getElementById('myDiv').style.marginTop="15px";
```

But how do I access the prefix `-webkit-`, if I want to give it a style like this example:

```
{-webkit-transition: width 1s;}
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You have two options:

- `style["-webkit-transition"]`
- `style.WebkitTransition`

The first directly works. The second notation is called camel case, and `foo-bar-baz` becomes `fooBarBaz`. As a result, when a non camel case string starts with `-`, the first letter is capitalized in camel case.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! This [article](http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/setcss3properties.shtml) suggests a similar syntax, but why isn't the fist letter in `msTransform` capitalized?

Answer (score 1):

One possibility would to use for example jquery, to make it easy.
If you want a pure javascript solution, then read this:
http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/setcss3properties.shtml

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to keep digging up those pesky style properties and their naming conventions you can always use jQuery to keep it simple.

```
$('#myDiv').css("-webkit-transition", "value");
```