# Uncaught ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment while using border-bottom CSS property in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, css

I am getting this error in JavaScript

> Uncaught ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment

At this line

```
function clicked(obj)
{
  obj.style.border-bottom='1px'; //error
}
```

I want to change a CSS property using a JavaScript function. I want to change `border-bottom` to `1px`. How do I achieve this from a function?

Comment: Semi-duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9438949.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It’s supposed to be

```
obj.style.borderBottom='1px';
```

CSS properties have to be camel-case in JS. Otherwise it’s interpreted as a subtraction.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
<script>
function clicked(obj)
{
  obj.style.borderBottom='1px';  
}
</script>
```