# How to make Datalist arrow to be always visible

Tags: css, html, html-datalist

I am trying to have datalist list element always visible. As standard after focused lost, the arrow disappears.

I would like to have it always like this: 
Here is the plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/?p=preview

```html
<input list="browsers" name="myBrowser" />
<datalist id="browsers">
  <option value="Chrome">
  <option value="Firefox">
  <option value="Internet Explorer">
  <option value="Opera">
  <option value="Safari">
</datalist>
```

[image]

ENVIRONMENT: Angular directive

Any ideas how to achieve it?

Best,

Comment: Is there a reason you're using a datalist element instead of a select?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to apply a CSS style on HTML5 datalist options?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13693482/is-there-a-way-to-apply-a-css-style-on-html5-datalist-options)

Comment: Hi. The reason behind using datalist over select was to have an option to type text. any idea how can I do it with select?

Comment: Browser-independent answer from here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39555400/1937033

Comment: The dropdown arrow should be shown by default by all browsers, damn it. :)

Answer (score 38, accepted):

I have got the arrow always visible using css:

```css
input::-webkit-calendar-picker-indicator {
              opacity: 100;
           }
```

```html
    <input list="browsers" name="myBrowser" />
    <datalist id="browsers">
      <option value="Chrome">
      <option value="Firefox">
      <option value="Internet Explorer">
      <option value="Opera">
      <option value="Safari">
    </datalist>
```

Comment: How would I set that style using jQuery/Javascript? I'm in a situation where I don't have access to the css (easily).

Comment: Hi. I could not set it using jQuery. You may have a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9438949/access-the-webkit-vendor-prefix-in-javascript

Comment: @amol01 any idea for Mozilla users? Do you have any reference page for `::calendar-picker-indicator` or compatibility table you could link? Tks

Comment: No idea why datalist having its css to include 'calendar' :)